# error in storing a string in a char* array

Tags: c, arrays, string

When I compile the following code and run it the code runs

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char* array[1];
    scanf("%s",array[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

but the following code doesn't run. It shows segmentation fault. Whats the reason.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char* array[2];
    scanf("%s",array[0]);
    scanf("%s",array[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

My input is bond in 1st case and 
James
Bond in 2nd

Comment: Both are UB as `array[]` is not initialized/assigned.

Comment: Wrong data type. You want char [], not char *[]. Make sure the array has room for the input data, and limit the number of characters you read. char line[1024]; fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin); is one, easy way.

Comment: PS: The first version works by luck only. The array allocates room for 1 pointer (4 or 8 bytes, typically). Try serving the program a string longer than 8 bytes, and then try to print it. ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault)

Comment: @chux if we do char *array[2]; array[0] = "my"; array[1] = "name"; It also works. I am doing the same thing using scanf?

Comment: @SahilKumar `char *array[2]; array[0] = "my";scanf("%s",array[0]);` is another form of UB.  Why have you not posted your input?

Comment: @SahilKumar there is a huge difference between `array[0] = "my";` and `scanf("%s", array[0])`. Infact there is nothing similar in them.

Comment: @BjornA no! Your explanation is not correct. He is passing `array[0]` not `&array[0]`. Even for strings less than 8 length it is UB because `array[0]` is uninitialised.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya You're right. Thanks for the correction. :)

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya ho can i use scanf to achieve the same purpose as is done by array[0] = "james"

Answer (score 0):

`array[1]` and `array[1]` are unitialised pointers.  You are therefore writing the data to an invalid or undefined location.  The pointers need to reference allocated memory.

Both code fragments are incorrect, but the thing about an unitialised pointer, it may contain a legal address, or an invalid address, but in any event the address is not defined.

```
char array[2][64];
scanf("%63s",array[0]);
scanf("%63s",array[1]);
```